# Not able to see Job History(http://localhost:19888) page in web browser in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

I am using **Hadoop version 2.4.1** on Ubuntu **14.04 32 bit**.
When I run a sample job using **hadoop jar user_jar.jar** command, I am not able to see output on **http://localhost:19888** **(Page not found)**
What could be the possible reason ?
Thank you in advance.

```
JPS output : 

3931 Jps
3719 NodeManager
3420 SecondaryNameNode
3593 ResourceManager
3246 DataNode
3126 NameNode
```

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>

</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>

</property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4):

Run mr-jobhistory-daemon:

```
$ $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh --config $HADOOP_CONFIG_DIR start historyserver
```

Now

`$ jps
2135 DataNode
2339 SecondaryNameNode
2627 NodeManager
3176 JobHistoryServer
1971 NameNode
3213 Jps
2485 ResourceManager`

and

`$ netstat -ntlp | grep 19888
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:19888         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3176/java`